# Make an item display only for certain period of time on the webpage

Tags: mysql, ajax, time, timestamp, display

Hi guys I am constructing a task distribution management system for my team in which I want to add a functionality that:

When I create a task, I will have an option to choose "how long is this task valid for being taken". For example, when creating the task I put "2 hours" in the

```
<input id="valid-for">
```

, then this task will only be displayed on the dashboard for 2 hours from the time it was created and then after 2 hours -> "display: none".

I've searched the web for the mechanism of achieving this feature but I didn't get a satisfied answer probably because I don't know the right terminology to google. I tried to use AJAX and use TIME_STAMP type attribute in MySQL but didn't know how to proceed. Could anybody tell me how to achieve this feature by the use of MySQL, jQuery or any other technics that could fulfill this feature? No code necessary I just need some explanation.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing any more details, here is how I would consider writing the code:

- In the database, have a start time and a use-by time.
- In your browser page, you can run a script periodically, say every minute (this is called polling). In this case, you can use Ajax to call back to the server for updates.
- At the server end, check for new tasks as well as expired tasks. Then send the results back to the Ajax caller.
- Back at the browser, update the dashboard accordingly.

I would be inclined to remove the task on the browser rather than simply hide it.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response Manngo! I will try this one and get back to you